# How do I replicate this footer in CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to replicate this footer on this [apple clone website](https://altcademy.github.io/apple_clone/), but I am having trouble.

1. keeping all the links the same color (I have tried removing the color purple using CSS `color: none;` and `text decoration: none;` but it still remains purple. And a link should only be underlined when my mouse hovers over it)
2. organizing everything in 5 equal columns. (I have tried using margins but I still can't get the headers in bold aligned with each other and equal width/length between columns)

Any answer can help! But please note that I am an amateur at coding, so I would really appreciate it if you could explain my mistakes.

```css
.container-footer {
  max-width: 5500px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-top: 98px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ebebe0;
  text-decoration-color:  #8a8a5c;
}

.ft-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

a.ft-title {
  color: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.col-5 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.col-6 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.col-7 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


.col-8 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.col-9 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.col-10 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer> 
<div class="container-footer">
  <div>
      <!-- Row 1: Shop and Learn  -->
      <div class="col-5">
        <h2 class="ft-title">Shop and Learn</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TV</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">iTunes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a<</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- -->
      </div>

<!-- Row 2: Apple Store  -->
      <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="ft-title">Apple Store</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Find a Store</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Genius Bar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Workshops and Learning</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Youth Programs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Apple Store App</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Refurbished</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Financing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reuse and Recycling</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Order Status</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shopping Help</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- -->
      </div>
<!-- Row 3: For Education & For Business  -->
     <div class="col-7">
       <h2 class="ft-title">For Education</h2>

       <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Apple and Education</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Shop for College</a></li>
       </ul>
       <ul>
         <h2 class="ft-title">For Business</h2>
         <li><a href="#">iPhone in Business</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">iPad in Business</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Mac in Business</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Shop for Your Business</a></li>
       </ul>
       <!-- -->
     </div>
<!-- Row 4: Account & Apple Values  -->
       <div class="col-8">
         <h2 class="ft-title">Account</h2>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Manage Your Apple ID</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Apple Store Account</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">iCloud.com</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
       <div class="col-9">
       <ul>
         <h2 class="ft-title">Apple Values</h2>
         <li><a href="#">Environment</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Supplier Responsibility</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Inclusion and Diversity</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
       </ul>
       <!-- -->
       </div>
<!-- Row 5: About Apple  -->
       <div class="col-10">
       <ul>
         <h2 class="ft-title">About Apple</h2>
         <li><a href="#">Apple Info</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Job Opportunities</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Press Info</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Hot News</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact Apple</a></li>
         <!-- -->
       </ul>
       </div>

       <h2>More ways to shop: Visit an <a href="#">Apple Store</a>, call 1-800-MY-APPLE, or find a <a href="#">reseller</a>.
       </h2>
       <h2>Copyright © 2016 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.&nbsp;</h2>
       Privacy Policy&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Terms of Use&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sales and Refunds&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Site Map
       <a href="#"><img src="./images/usa.png"</a>

  </div>
</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `display:flex` to the container to order columns and set

```
a:active,
a:visited,
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

To control your links color

```css
.container-footer {
  max-width: 5500px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-top: 98px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ebebe0;
  text-decoration-color: #8a8a5c;
}

.cont{
  display: flex;
}
a:active,
a:visited,
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.ft-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

a.ft-title {
  color: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.col-5 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.col-6 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.col-7 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.col-8 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.col-9 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.col-10 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container-footer">
    <div class="cont">
      <!-- Row 1: Shop and Learn  -->
      <div class="col-5">
        <h2 class="ft-title">Shop and Learn</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Mac</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">iPad</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Watch</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TV</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">iTunes</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a<</li>
        </ul>
        <!-- -->
      </div>

<!-- Row 2: Apple Store  -->
      <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="ft-title">Apple Store</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Find a Store</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Genius Bar</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Workshops and Learning</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Youth Programs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Apple Store App</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Refurbished</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Financing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reuse and Recycling</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Order Status</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shopping Help</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- -->
      </div>
      <!-- Row 3: For Education & For Business  -->
      <div class="col-7">
        <h2 class="ft-title">For Education</h2>

        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Apple and Education</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop for College</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
          <h2 class="ft-title">For Business</h2>
          <li><a href="#">iPhone in Business</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">iPad in Business</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mac in Business</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop for Your Business</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- -->
      </div>
      <!-- Row 4: Account & Apple Values  -->
      <div class="col-8">
        <h2 class="ft-title">Account</h2>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Manage Your Apple ID</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Apple Store Account</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">iCloud.com</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <ul>
          <h2 class="ft-title">Apple Values</h2>
          <li><a href="#">Environment</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Supplier Responsibility</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Inclusion and Diversity</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!-- -->
      </div>
      <!-- Row 5: About Apple  -->
      <div class="col-10">
        <ul>
          <h2 class="ft-title">About Apple</h2>
          <li><a href="#">Apple Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Job Opportunities</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Press Info</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Investors</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Hot News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Legal</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Apple</a></li>
          <!-- -->
        </ul>
      </div>

    
  </div>
    <h2>More ways to shop: Visit an <a href="#">Apple Store</a>, call 1-800-MY-APPLE, or find a <a href="#">reseller</a>.
      </h2>
      <h2>Copyright © 2016 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.&nbsp;</h2>
      Privacy Policy&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Terms of Use&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sales and Refunds&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Site Map
      <a href="#"><img src="./images/usa.png" </a>

    </div>
</footer>
```